# How to give phpmyadmin access through the webmail in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

I added the user from user management but I don't know what to do further how to check?

I am expecting to user don't access public html folder.

Answer (score 0):

User will be able to access the public html folder, if they are accessing it through cPanel. Unfortunately, there is no way around this as phpMyAdmin is secured with cPanel authentication.

However, you could install your own phpMyAdmin on your domain and provide access through it. You can find more information about how to do it [here](https://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/cpanel/how-do-i-install-phpmyadmin-onto-my-account).

Comment: after Visit http://yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin/setup in the server login page appears...so what can i do?

Comment: Step 17: Now you can log directly into your phpmyadmin without accessing the cPanel.  For the username and password, just use the username and password for one of your databases.  To find the user assigned to your database, login to your cPanel and access the MySQL Databases section